# A=(-infinity,0,+infinity),is n(A) thus odd?

Tags: combinatorics

There is an negative number for every positive number and there’s zero.Thus,an odd number of numbers exist right?

Comment: This question uses some nonstandard notation. Specifically, what do you mean by $(-\infty,0,\infty)?$ Do you just mean the real numbers? And is $n(A)$ the cardinality of $A?$

Comment: Like what I mean is the set of all integers would have an odd number of elements?

Comment: We usually write $\mathbb Z$ for the integers. If you don’t know how to get the fancy Z, a regular $Z$.

Answer (score 0):

No.  It is not a meaningful statement, given that there is an infinite cardinality of numbers

There are as many integers as there are non-zero integers, but if the the latter were even using your argument then the former would also be even as well as being odd

Similarly there are as many real numbers as there are non-zero real numbers, but if the the latter were even using your argument then the former would also be even as well as being odd

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to preface this 'proof' that an even number of numbers exist with a comment that infinity is difficult to understand

There is $0$ and there is $1$. For every other number we can pair it with $1-n$ so there is a negative number for every positive number except $1$ so with the same logic infinity would be even.

So it can't be either so saying infinity is odd or even is meaningless (also there isn't just 1 'type' of infinity)

Comment: Like what I mean is the set of all integers would have an odd number of elements?

Comment: (a) It doesn't make sense to say that the set has an odd (or even) number of elements because (b) You can prove it has an odd number (as you did) and that it has an even number (as I did) and (c) those are mutually exclusive under all definitions I know

Comment: Okay, so infinity has no certain characteristics like odd and even?

Comment: Yes - Infinity doesn't have certain characteristics that integers have

Comment: Thanks for that one